# "claimants" How is this word used here?

Tags: grammaticality

Isn't this [**article**](https://money.yahoo.com/us-chamber-calls-for-ending-the-extra-300-in-unemployment-benefits-after-disappointing-jobs-report-151828040.html?.tsrc=fp_deeplink)'s line strange?

> **"This labor shortage is being created in large part by the supplemental unemployment payments that the federal government provides claimants on top of their state unemployment benefits,**" Gov. Henry McMaster said in a statement on Thursday. "What was intended to be a short-term financial assistance for the vulnerable and displaced during the height of the pandemic has turned into a dangerous federal entitlement, incentivizing and paying workers to stay at home rather than encouraging them to return to the workplace."

[**Claimant**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/claimant)

> A claimant is someone who is receiving money from the state because they are unemployed or they are unable to work because they are ill.

May be the author dropped "as" between "provides" and "claimants"?

Thank you.

Comment: It’s fine. “payments that the government provides (people who are unemployed/ill)” Why do you think it’s wrong exactly?

Comment: In the old days I think people would have inserted a _to_ so giving _provides to claimants_ but these days small words seem to disappear.

Comment: @mdewey Oh thanks. Even to "newer" people this kind of complex thoughts packed sentence is "easy". link [ https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/283468/two-questions-about-a-line ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, a person who makes an application for state benefits is called a 'claimant', because they are 'claiming' what they believe they are entitled to.

Your text is saying that the claimants (people who already receive state unemployment benefits) are being paid supplemental unemployment payments as well.

There is nothing omitted from the grammar - if you substitute the word 'claimants' with 'people', hopefully you will see it makes sense.